# angularjs: extending directive then make modifications

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, servicenow

I am working in ServiceNow and am trying to extend an ootb directive, then make some modifications to a couple functions.  So far I've figured out how to extend the directive:

```
function (spModelDirective){
    return angular.extend({}, spModelDirective[0], {
        templateUrl:'lbl_custom_template.xml'
    });
}
```

Within this directive, there's a function called getNestedFields that I would like to make edits to:

```
function getNestedFields(fields, containers) {
    if (!containers)
        return;
    for (var _container in containers) {
        var container = containers[_container];
        if (container.columns) {
            for (var _col in container.columns) {
                var col = container.columns[_col];
                for (var _field in col.fields) {
                    var field = col.fields[_field];
                    if (field.type == "container" && container.caption != "")
                        getNestedFields(fields, [field]);
                    else if (field.type == "checkbox_container")
                        getNestedFields(fields, field.containers);
                    else if (field.type == "field" || container.caption=="")
                        fields.push(formModel._fields[field.name]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone provide some guidance on what the correct syntax for this would be?

**More information**

Our team cloned the ootb widget-form and am trying to create a custom layout.  Basically, we want each form section to be it's own tab much like the back-end form instead of one long form, which is what the ootb widget-form currently does.  In the very first line of the sp-variable-layout template, it shows:

```
<fieldset ng-init="$last ? execItemScripts() : null" ng-show="isContainerVisible(container)" ng-repeat="container in containers">
```

The ng-repeat of container in containers considers each form section as a separate container (which is perfect), BUT it also considers any splits as a separate container as well.  So for example, if my form's layout looks like this:

[image]

This will create two tabs:  one that has every field within the begin and end splits AND a separate tab with everything after the end split.  The JSON object that is created looks like this:

```
{
        "_bootstrap_cells": 6,
        "_count": 2,
        "visible": true,
        "columns": [{
            "fields": [{
                "name": "type_of_account",
                "type": "field"
            }, {
                "name": "routing_transit_number",
                "type": "field"
            }]
        }, {
            "fields": [{
                "name": "type_of_payment",
                "type": "field"
            }, {
                "name": "check_digit",
                "type": "field"
            }]
        }],
        "caption": "Direct Deposit",
        "id": "b456b9d2137ac340177c36328144b0ef",
        "scope_name": "x_dnf_table"
    }, {
        "_bootstrap_cells": 12,
        "_count": 1,
        "visible": true,
        "columns": [{
            "fields": [{
                "name": "account_number",
                "type": "field"
            }, {
                "name": "account_title",
                "type": "field"
            }, {
                "name": "financial_institution_name",
                "type": "field"
            }]
        }],
        "caption": "",
        "id": "",
        "scope_name": "x_dnf_table"
    }
```

Notice the first "section" has a caption, but ServiceNow treats the split section as its own separate section with no caption at all.

I want to change the spModel directive to produce only containers with captions as their own tab and if a container does NOT have a caption, to append it to the previous container that does have a caption.

Comment: Please explain what you want to change.

Comment: hi @TomasBy, i provided some more information above, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can edit this function as this is hosted as a file on Servicenow.  See https://hi.service-now.com/scripts/app.$sp/directive.spModel.js then just control-f for the getNestedFields.

Per this thread; https://community.servicenow.com/thread/247907#1059129 I believe spModal is just a wrapper for $uibModal.

What you can do is make your own directive on sp_angular_provider.

Comment: hi @jace, just for clarification I'm trying to modify spModel and not spModal.  You are right, I've actually created my own directive, but am hoping to extend spModel (which I've done), but make some modifications to that one function so I can get a tabbed format.  Thanks!